# Imagining electric flux intuitively

Tags: electrostatic

I know that electric field doesn't really flow, so whenever I'm trying to imagine electric flux like an amount of water passing through a window intuitively, I can't relate these two things.

Can somebody out there give me a more precise intuitive feeling other than the rain analogy so that I can develop a better feel for electric flux? (I'm comfortable with the intuitive feeling of electric field.)

PS: This may not be a hardcore engineering topic, so if the moderators thinks so please redirect this to the appropriate section (in that case pardon for posting here.)

Comment: "*precise intuitive feelings*" <-- there's a contradiction somewhere in there.

Comment: Well what i mean to say is , a better analogy

Comment: Maye this will help you understand it: https://betterexplained.com/articles/flux/

Comment: isn't it a lot like imagining magnetic flux?

Answer (score 0):

Its been shown that a precise analogy (math solution, to differential equations) exists between electric fields in vacuum or air, and electric fields inside a conductive sheet of carbon_particle_loaded paper.

The constraint of the field lines is that at a highly_conducting surface, the field lines MUST ARRIVE at the surface at exactly 90 degrees (orthogonal to the surface). Any tangential component will cause lateral movement of electrons, causing re_arranging of charges at the surface, until orthogonal flux/field lines become sufficient to describe the field at the surface.

So draw thee some surfaces, and start sketching lines flowing between them,

Two surfaces at 90 degrees, such as two isolated metal pieces that (almost) form a corner, is good place to start.

I recall old versions of Schaums Outline had these sketches.